# Adding a CA certificate for client certificates

Tags: winapi, cryptography, cryptoapi

I'm writing a server application that uses CryptoAPI and Schannel for setting up a secure SSL connection to clients. The server requires the clients to submit a certificate for verification (by setting the `ASC_REQ_MUTUAL_AUTH` flag in `AcceptSecurityContext`).

The problem I have is that some clients (namely clients using `javax.net.ssl`) does not pass along their client certificate (even though it's been configured to do so). I suspect this is because the CA certificate used for signing the client certificates are not in the list of CA's passed to the client during the handshake.

I've tried to do variations of the following to add the CA certificate to this list:

```cpp
PCERT_CONTEXT caCertContext = ...; /* Imported from a DER formatted file */

HCERTSTORE systemStore = CertOpenStore(
                CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM,
                0,
                0,
                CERT_STORE_OPEN_EXISTING_FLAG |
                    CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                L"ROOT");

bool ok = CertAddCertificateContextToStore(
                systemStore,
                caCertContext,
                CERT_STORE_ADD_USE_EXISTING,
                NULL);

if (!ok)
{
    std::cerr << "Could not add certificate to system store!" << std::endl;
}
```

In the above example `CertAddCertificateContextToStore`always fails. If I change `CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE`to `CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER` I am presented with a popup asking me to confirm the certificate, but even if I accept the CA certificate will not appear in the list sent to the client.

I also tried extending the system store collection with a temporary memory store (something I picked up from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557710/winhttp-how-to-use-a-temporary-certificate-store)) but to no avail.

Anyone know of a way to solve this? Ideally programmatically without using any GUI or external tool?

Comment: What is the value returned from GetLastError() after calling CertAddCertificateContextToStore()? I do something quite similar but use CertAddEncodedCertificateToStore() with success.

Comment: GetLastError() returns "5", whatever that's supposed to mean... Edit: seems like error 5 is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because you don't have permission to access the store as read and write, you can only access it as read. So what you have to do is add CERT_STORE_READONLY_FLAG so it will be:

```
HCERTSTORE systemStore = CertOpenStore(
            CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM,
            0,
            0,
            CERT_STORE_OPEN_EXISTING_FLAG |
                CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE | CERT_STORE_READONLY_FLAG ,
            L"ROOT");
```

If you which to make changes to your store and not have it read only that means you will require administration elevation when you are running your C++ application.

Comment: But if it is read only, how can I programatically extend the collection of CA certificates? Note that I do not want it added to the system store, since that would make it global for all applications on that machine.

Comment: I edit my answer. You need to elevate your application to Administrator privileges in order to make changes to the store. I know I solved one of my issues this way so you could try that. You can do that by adding this <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator"/> to your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add it systemwide (as you mentioned in the comment) you can open with the [`CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certopenstore) flag.

```
CertOpenStore(CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, 0, 0, CERT_STORE_OPEN_EXISTING_FLAG |
              CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER, L"MY");
```