# Installing self-signed certificate programmatically in a service

Tags: winapi, windows-services, self-signed

I am trying to silently install a self-signed certificate in a service but it returns an error. Here is my code:

```
  if(!CertAddEncodedCertificateToSystemStore("ROOT", (BYTE *) data, dataSize))
     DWORD error = GetLastError();
```

error is 1223 ERROR_CANCELLED how can I install a self-signed certificate in a service?

Edit: My code works when run under a normal user application and a dialogue is shown asking if I want to install the certificate but I want to be able to silently install the certificate from my service.

Comment: Does it work from a desktop app? IIRC some of these functions display a confirmation dialog, does this?

Comment: Yes it does but and it displays a confirmation dialog but I want to install a certificate in a silent way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Root CA Cert via code on Win32](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656706/installing-root-ca-cert-via-code-on-win32)

Comment: No it isn't because I am asking a different question I already know how to install a root certificate I just want to be able to do it from a service in a silent manner.

Comment: The linked question (or one of the answers) does discuss dialog vs no dialog - that's why I thought it was the same issue, or at least that they're related.

Comment: I have already seen this question and they say that a process running under the SYSTEM account I should be able to install it without a dialogue silently but this does not work for me.

Comment: It wouldn't be surprising if Windows requires user consent for such a potentially risky operation.